# Is there any good tutorial or book for teaching uncoupled software architecture?

Tags: books, design

We see many open source software have many open plugin features and uncoupled character.

Such as Wordpress, WHMCS, and Cacti software. They let 3rd party developers to develop plugins, add-ons, and other modules.

So, this is a very good feature for the open source software.

Is there any good book or tutorial to instruct or teaching the ideology or techniques?